# Unintended Row Movement When Working between Two Workbooks. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get this code to find the WO# from the shipping list and move rows on the master list. Everything works correctly, EXCEPT, it always moves the second row on the master list and I cant figure out why. Here is the code for the check and row movement.

```
Function NextWorkday(ByVal dt As Date) As Date
    Dim nextDate As Date
    nextDate = dt + 1
    While Weekday(nextDate) = vbSaturday Or Weekday(nextDate) = vbSunday
        nextDate = nextDate + 1
    Wend
    NextWorkday = nextDate
End Function

Sub InstallMove()
    Dim userName As String
    userName = Environ$("Username")

    Dim datePull As Date
    datePull = NextWorkday(Date)

    Dim shippingFilePath As String
    If userName = "Christina" Then
        shippingFilePath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\OneDrive - wilde-signs.com\Production List\Pam's Daily List\" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & " " & Year(Date) & "\Shipping Tally_" & Format(Now, "MMMM_dd_yy") & ".xlsm"
    Else
        shippingFilePath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\OneDrive - wilde-signs.com\Christina Wilde\Production List\Pam's Daily List\" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & " " & Year(Date) & "\Shipping Tally_" & Format(Now, "MMMM_dd_yy") & ".xlsm"
    End If

    Dim shippingWsName As String
    shippingWsName = "Shipping"

    Dim masterFilePath As String
    If userName = "Christina" Then
        masterFilePath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\OneDrive - wilde-signs.com\Production List\" & Format(Date, "MMMM yyyy") & "\Production List_" & Format(datePull, "MM_dd_yy") & ".xlsm"
    Else
        masterFilePath = "C:\Users\" & userName & "\OneDrive - wilde-signs.com\Christina Wilde\Production List\" & Format(Date, "MMMM yyyy") & "\Production List_" & Format(datePull, "MM_dd_yy") & ".xlsm"
    End If

    Dim masterWsName As String
    masterWsName = "Sheet1"

    Dim shippingWb As Workbook
    Set shippingWb = Workbooks.Open(shippingFilePath)

    Dim masterWb As Workbook
    Set masterWb = Workbooks.Open(masterFilePath)

    Dim shippingWs As Worksheet
    Set shippingWs = shippingWb.Worksheets(shippingWsName)

    Dim masterWs As Worksheet
    Set masterWs = masterWb.Worksheets(masterWsName)

    Dim lastRowShipping As Long
    lastRowShipping = shippingWs.Cells(shippingWs.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastRowMaster As Long
    lastRowMaster = masterWs.Cells(masterWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim shippingRange As Range
    Set shippingRange = shippingWs.Range("F4:F" & lastRowShipping)

    Dim masterRange As Range
    Set masterRange = masterWs.Range("B1:B" & lastRowMaster)

    Dim shippingCell As Range
    Dim keywordCell As Range
    Dim keyword As String

    Dim foundKeywords As String

    Dim insertOffset As Long

    For Each shippingCell In shippingRange
        If Not IsEmpty(shippingCell) Then
            keyword = shippingWs.Cells(shippingCell.Row, "B").Value

            Set keywordCell = masterRange.Find(keyword, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not keywordCell Is Nothing Then
                Dim insertRow As Long
                insertRow = keywordCell.Row + 1 + insertOffset

                Dim installRow As Range
                Set installRow = masterWs.Columns("A:A").Find("INSTALL READY/DELIVERY/SHIPPING/INVOICING", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

                If Not installRow Is Nothing Then
                    If keywordCell.Row < installRow.Row Then
                        masterWs.Rows(keywordCell.Row).Cut
                        masterWs.Rows(installRow.Row + insertOffset + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                        masterWs.Cells(installRow.Row + insertOffset, "B").Value = "Install"
                        insertOffset = insertOffset + 1
                        foundKeywords = foundKeywords & keyword & ", "
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shippingCell

    Dim emailText As String
    emailText = shippingWs.Range("G2").Value

    Dim emailBody As String
    emailBody = "Dear Christina and Jake," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find the following text from cell G2 of the Shipping worksheet:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & emailText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Best regards," & vbCrLf & "Your Name"

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    outlookMail.To = "Christina@wilde-signs.com; Jake@wilde-signs.com"
    outlookMail.Subject = "Shipping Information"
    outlookMail.Body = emailBody
    outlookMail.Send

    Set outlookMail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here are screenshots of what the shipping and master list look like for reference.

Master:[image]

Shipping:[image]

Comment: A little difficult to debug without setting up the whole environment - have you tried stepping through to see where things are going wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to figure out that B1 was returning as a "nonblank" and an empty string because the A1 and B1 are merged. 

I'm still very new and I would never have thought to step through considering I didn't know the tool existed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.